# Where can I find the UUIDs for TI SensorTag services?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have been working through the book *Getting Started with Bluetooth Low Energy* and have fished around on the TI site.  TI must have taken down the Android sample that I have seen referenced, I have found the attribute table, but would like to see a document with the UUIDs that I get back from uiAvailableServices callback.  I am using the Bluetooth Application Accelerator.

Answer (score 5):

All UUIDs for Gatt Services and Characteristics are listed in this document:

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/images/a/a8/BLE_SensorTag_GATT_Server.pdf

Comment: Unfortunately, page no longer exists. ;-(

Answer (score 0):

For a detailed list of TI SensorTag provided services and their UUIDs, please take a look at [Gatt Services in this document](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/SensorTag_User_Guide#Gatt_Server).

In your app, you should be able to match the UUIDs you got from the device with the one's in the above spec.

Comment: Thanks, this gives the UUIDs of the characteristics, I am pretty sure that the UUID of the service is simply one less than the first characteristic's UUID, that is (short form) aa11 is the first characteristic for the accelerometer and aa10 is the UUID of the service.  I was just thinking the services UUIDs would have been documented somewhere.